# PHP : I'm not able to append variable's data onto a link

Tags: php, html

Im trying to get some data from the array into new variables and trying to append those data in a link.
I'm new to scripting stuff.

Here's the code:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php 

$long = $info['lognitude']; 
$lati = $info['latitude'] ;


?> 

<a href="http://www.maps.google.com/?q=$lati,$long">Click Here To See On Maps</a> 



</body>
</html>
```

I know its a simple question but as im new to scripting please help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put your variables inside php tags.

```
<a href="http://www.maps.google.com/?q=<?php echo $lati; ?>,<?php echo $long; ?>">Click Here To See On Maps</a>
```

We cud also use string interpolation like this:

```
<a href="http://www.maps.google.com/?q=<?php echo "$lati,$long"; ?>">Click Here To See On Maps</a>
```

Note that we also uses `echo` to actually print the output to the document.

Comment: Its not working for me, as im clicking on the hyperlink it opens following link : https://maps.google.com/?q=,

Comment: Did you remember to use `echo`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to enclose your variables with `<?=$var?>` in the html code.

`<?=$variable?>` is a shortcut for `<?php echo $variable; ?>`

Comment: This may not work for everyone out of box. `short_open_tag` must be enabled.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag

Comment: As far as I know it is enabled by default from php 5.4

Comment: Yes that is true. Just wanted to point it out if anyone still uses an outdated PHP version.

Answer (score 0):

You closed the PHP tag before the link so the PHP processor never processes the variables in the link.  You could do something like this to fix it, assuming the variables have been initialized properly:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php 
$long = $info['lognitude']; 
$lati = $info['latitude'] ;


echo "<a href='http://www.maps.google.com/?q=$lati,$long'>Click Here To See On Maps</a>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing php tags. Next time try to google such stuff first.

`<a href="http://www.maps.google.com/?q=<?php print $lati.','.$long ?>">Click Here To See On Maps</a>`

Or

`<a href="http://www.maps.google.com/?q=<?php print $lati ?>,<?php print $long ?>">Click Here To See On Maps</a>`

FYI, you can either "print" or "echo", doesn't really matters.

Comment: Its not working for me, as im clicking on the hyperlink it opens following link : maps.google.com/?q=,

Comment: Siddhart Sachdeva that's because your $lati and $long variables are empty.